# How to alphabetically sort of a string delimited by commas and sort alphabetically by members last name?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a string like so:

```
students="John Dee johndee@gmail.com 555-555-5555,Jane Bee janebee@gmail.com 555-555-5555,Sarah Zee sarahzee@gmail.com 555-555-5555"
```

I want to take this string and separate it by its commas then sort it by the last names. I think to do this I might have to use the split function, then loop it, save each item into a list then some how sort by the 1st index. Not sure how to do this.

What I have so far:

```
def alphaOrder(students):
    mylist = []
    splitter = students.split(',')

    for i in splitter:
        mylist.append(i)

    mylist.sort(key=lambda n: split(' ')[1])
    print(mylist)

alphaOrder(students)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic can be simplified, as `sorted` has a `key` argument:

```
res = sorted(students.split(','), key=lambda x: x.split()[1])

['Jane Bee janebee@gmail.com 555-555-5555',
 'John Dee johndee@gmail.com 555-555-5555',
 'Sarah Zee sarahzee@gmail.com 555-555-5555']
```

Note that `str.split` defaults to whitespace, so `str.split(' ')` is not required. In addition, `str.split` returns a `list` object, so there's no need to manually iterate and `append`.